# PHP variable error

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to add another varable where on doesn't exist. It is a posting app where you enter 2 text boxes and it is posted. It originally came with one variable with for the body. i wanted to add body1 to it as well. The functions.php deifines the first one upon adding the second, I got this: 
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')' in /home/a1893806/public_html/functions.php on line 20` Here is the modified code:

```
<?php

function add_post($userid,$body,$body1){
    $sql = "insert into posts (user_id, body, body1, stamp) 
            values ($userid, '". mysql_real_escape_string($body,$body1). "',now())";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
function show_posts($userid){
    $posts = array();

    $sql = "select body, stamp from posts
     where user_id = '$userid' order by stamp desc";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
        $posts[] = array(   'stamp' => $data->stamp, 
                            'userid' => $userid, 
                            'body' => $data->body
                            'body1' => $data->body1
            );
    }
    return $posts;

}
?>
```

It originally doesn't have: `'body1' => $data->body1` or any of the body1 variables

I'm not sure why I can't have the 2 textboxes in the post.

Comment: Don't add new questions into your first question.

Comment: Oh, and please don't sign your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 tables inside each other:

```
<table class="imagetable">
<table align="center" border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' width='300'>
```

This is not allowed.

```
function add_post($userid,$body,$body1){
    $sql = "insert into posts (user_id, body, body1, stamp) 
        values ($userid, '". mysql_real_escape_string($body,$body1). "',now())";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Must be

```
function add_post($userid,$body,$body1){
    $sql = "
       INSERT into posts (user_id, body, body1, stamp) 
        VALUE (".$userid.", '". mysql_real_escape_string($body) ."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($body1). "', NOW())";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

And I personally prefer this for readability:

```
    $sql = "
       INSERT into posts
          SET user_id = ".$userid."
            , body = '". mysql_real_escape_string($body) ."'
            , body1 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($body1). "'
            , stamp = NOW()
```

Something more trivial; `body1` doesn't make much sense.. 1; it is actually number 2. 2; Why would you have 2 body's? Makes no sense? Maybe `body` should be `intro` and `body1`: `body`? (I know it's not too important, but makes it easier to understand)

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a comma after the body element of the `$posts` array:

```
// Bad
'body' => $data->body

// Good
'body' => $data->body,
```

Not sure you can do this:

```
$sql = "insert into posts (user_id, body, body1, stamp) 
        values ($userid, '". mysql_real_escape_string($body,$body1). "',now())";
```

Try this:

```
$sql = "insert into posts (user_id, body, body1, stamp) 
        values ($userid, '". mysql_real_escape_string($body) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($body1). "',now())";
```

Comment: Great! But it's not posting the second text box's code> I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing , in your $posts array